# I got a weird offer to work at promising startup. Should I accept?

Tags: job-offer, startup, business

So here is the thing. My friend has offered me 3-5% at VERY promising startup. It has already 10 elite programmers and their plan is very cool. It's actually very low-level startup and they are creating new technology which makes cloud apps 30 % more efficient with zero additional costs (roughly speaking).

The offer is - after 3 years I can take 3-5 % of the company or $100k in cash (which is a lot for the Czech Republic). Problem is - I would have NO salary for at least 1.5 year (but free rent at cheap flat and free food) and I will get NOTHING if I leave before the third year.

I doubt I can stay there for 3 years without almost any money.

What do you think? Is it worth the risk? I am 19 btw. I think I would at least gain a lot of lucrative knowledge but the price is kinda high

Right now I have awesome job as a react programmer. Good money, new macbook, discounts on food etc.

Comment: working for free is generally not a great idea.

Comment: Hi Mr. Robot. Welcome to StackExchange. We are a bit different from other sites. Here you can only ask factual questions with factual answers. "What do you think" questions are off topic. Please have a look at [our help pages](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) if you have not already done so

Comment: So 33k USD / year (which it won't be, due to tax complications of lump sum). [PayScale](https://www.payscale.com/research/CZ/Job=Software_Developer/Salary) gives average Czech software dev sallary at $24k USD, and entry-level at $22k, with no "risk of losing it all". Doesn't seem like a great deal.

Comment: @RJFalconer only if the OP takes 100K and not 3-5%, and only if anyone has 100K at the 3 year mark and/or the company is worth anything, and the OP is only working without salary for 1.5 years, so your maths is a little off (but we don't know what the salary would be)

Comment: If they can employ 10 "elite" "programmers", why can't they pay you a salary?

Comment: Is there anything preventing them from firing you after 3 - epsilon years?

Comment: "new technology which makes cloud apps 30 % more efficient with zero additional costs" - this alone should be ringing alarm bells.  Isn't this also the plot of "Betas"?!

Comment: @Studoku I bet they can afford to hire 100 "elite programmers" that don't get paid. Well, I wouldn't call myself an "elite programmer" (WTF???) but I'm sure they can't afford to hire me. Because I take cash.

Comment: A cool technology that makes web applications 30% more efficient at no additional costs, except if that’s the case, how does the startup plan to make money?  You should be cautious of any business plan, that plans to make money from a technology, that makes something more efficient at no additional costs.  It’s sounds like the technology is easily reproduced if it costs no money to implement

Answer (score 16):

> What do you think?

In my opinion, working for free is crazy (*or for the promise of a way in the future payout*).  If you can code, **you can get a paying job** right now in most countries.  How are you going to pay expenses other than food in the meantime?

> Is it worth the risk?

IMO no, it is not.  Many start up's start, not many become profitable or even stick around very long.  Also if you leave say in 2 years because of some other factor, you will have definitely gotten hosed.

Comment: +1, but its not just crazy its STUPID. What your (OPs) friend is not telling you is that if the company way makes no money you get 0. Also if you get fired before the 3 year mark you get 0. You are taking on risk 3 year of work with no compensation for that risk. You should be a partner NOW. Also i your friend is abusing the friendship , no way the 10 Devs are working under this same agreement.

Comment: @Morons "your friend is abusing the friendship" - this is not a friend.

Comment: @Morons, I'd really, really doubt that there are ten programmers involved.  That would be a really high number for a startup.  If I got an offer like that, I'd want to be introduced to the programmers, and talk briefly with two or three random ones.  Then I'd insist on a signed contract and take it to a lawyer or other person who can go through it, and sign nothing if there was any way for the startup to fail to pay me other than by going broke (and startups tend to do that).  Also, I'd make sure the free rent and food was in the contract.